# Uploading a small sized image to server using php and android

Tags: java, php, android, eclipse

On PHP Side I am using following Code

```
    $val = (isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : null);
        $isUploaded = false;
        return $val;
        if($val != null)
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $mainPath))
            {
                $isUploaded = true;
            }
        }
```

Android side I am using

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file", Base64Coder.encodeLines(imageArray)));

HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection-manager.timeout", 15000);
        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
             httppost.setEntity(entity);
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

However

```
   $val = (isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : null);
```

returns null

How can I upload image properly

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106 A Similar link might help perhaps

Comment: Your doing an HttpPost but then you look for query strings ? ($_GET['file'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code for upload, and it's work. You need import [httpmime jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime401jar.htm)

PHP code

```
$uploads_dir = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/Upload/upload/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo $_POST["contentString"]."\n";
    echo  "File path = ".$uploads_dir;
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir);
} else {
    echo "\n Upload Error";
    echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
    print_r($_FILES);
```

JAVA code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://localhost/Upload/index.php");

File file = new File(filePath);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
FileBody contentFile = new FileBody(file);
entity.addPart("userfile",contentFile);

StringBody contentString = new StringBody("This is contentString");
entity.addPart("contentString",contentString);

postMethod.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(postMethod);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
String state = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = (isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : null);
```

Replace with

```
$val = (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) ? $_FILES['file']['name'] : null);
```

Check manual for available fields for post method uploads.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: I changed but still Null

Comment: Your problem looks on android side. http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106. You need to specify `enctype` as `multipart/form-data` when uploading files.